# Angulars HostListener interfers with focused HTML object

Tags: angular

I have two components, `NavBarComponent` and `FooComponent`.

I attached a [HostListener](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) to `FooComponent` and I have an input field in `NavBarComponent`.

**FooComponent**

```js
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent): void { 
    switch (event.code) {
        case 'ArrowLeft': {
            /* do something in this component */
            $event.stopPropagation();
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Despite the fact that `document.activeElement` returns the `<input ...>` field from the navigation component, the FooComponent consumes the `<-- arrow left` event.

Of course, that happens because I call `stopPropagation`, but I assumed the listener wouldn't get the event at all since the input field has the focus. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does get the event since `'document:keydown'` (or `'window:keydown'`) is a global hook.

What you might want to do is to skip your code when the `FooComponent` or any of its children inside DOM are not the target. Something like this:

```js
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
  switch (event.code) {
    case 'ArrowLeft': {
      if (this.elemRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
        /* do something in this component */
        event.stopPropagation();
        break;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

And then add this dependency inside the constructor:

```js
constructor(
  private elemRef: ElementRef,
```

This should allow you to use the left arrow key inside the input box of the `NavBarComponent`.

---

By the way, for me in Chrome, the event is not actually prevented until I also add `return false;` immediately after `event.stopPropagation();`. As far as I know, it's always a good practice to return also a falsy value when you want to cancel an event.

Comment: perfect answer, thanks a lot!